# python - how to get discord user that reacted to a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to get the user id that reacted to a message, here's my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
   message_id = 'message_id_here'
   if reaction.message_id == message_id:
      user = reaction.user
      print(user)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the help center? Your question doesn’t abide by much of what is mentioned in [ask], [mcve]. Honestly, how do you expect people to help you based on 5 random lines of code with basically no explanation? Consider yourself lucky that someone either went above and beyond or encountered the exact same issue recently, eh.

Comment: Owh i edited some part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payload that gets passed to [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) is a [`RawReactionActionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) object.
As the error says, `RawReactionActionEvent` does not have a `user` attribute. Instead, you can simply use the [`user_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.user_id) attribute.